# Show all posts exept of users that you follow Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have made an Instagram like web-application with laravel 7.

The $posts are displayed in DESC order like so: (This is in the PostController)

```
    public function index()
    {
        // All the users that are followed
        $users = auth()->user()->following()->pluck('profiles.user_id');

        // All the posts from those users
        $posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $users)->with('user')->latest()->paginate(5);

        return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }
```

I want to create a new view named explore.blade.php. The content needs to be the latest post from all the users that are not being followed. 
This `$posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $users)->with('user')->latest()->paginate(5);` needs to be inversed so that these get left out.

Comment: `$posts = Post::whereNotIn('user_id', $users)->with('user')->latest()->paginate(5);`?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert That worked, thank you

Comment: Great, I'll add it as an answer - it may help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `whereNotIn()`:

```
$posts = Post::whereNotIn('user_id', $users)->with('user')->latest()->paginate(5);
```